# My codewars solution works fine locally in Visual Studio, but causes an error when passing tests on codewars' side

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation

**!!! CONTAINS SPOILERS TO CODEWARS TASKS !!!**

Given the following task

[image: A task from CodeWars]

I came up with the following solution:

```
Pair** removNb(long long n, int* length)
{
    int idx = 0;
    Pair* pairs = malloc(0);

    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; i += 1)
    {
        for (long long j = 1; j <= n; j += 1)
        {
            long long product = i * j;
            long long sum = 0;
            for (long long g = 1; g <= n; g += 1)
            {
                if (g != i && g != j)
                {
                    sum += g;
                }    
            }

            if (product == sum)
            {
                pairs = realloc(pairs, (idx + 1) * sizeof(Pair));
                pairs[idx].first = i;
                pairs[idx].snd = j;
                idx += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    *length = idx;
    return &pairs;
}
```

And tested it locally in Visual Studio, all seems to work fine (even tho I get some warnings about memory reallocation, but I'm new to C and am trying to just get things to work for now. Any advice on this is also appreciated tho)

*But when I try to test this solution in CodeWars, I get the following prompt:*
[image: Error prompt from codewards]

It seems they use the [Criterion](https://github.com/Snaipe/Criterion) library for testing solutions. This is the testing code from there:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <criterion/criterion.h>

typedef struct Pair Pair;
struct Pair {
    long long first;
    long long snd;
};

Pair** removNb(long long n, int* length);
// fct  to compare results; sz number of pairs / Pair** arr will be freed
char* array2StringData(Pair** arr, int sz);

void dotest(long long n, char* sexpr) {
    int lg = 0;
    Pair** act = removNb(n, &lg);
    char* sact = array2StringData(act, lg);
    if(strcmp(sact, sexpr) != 0)
        printf("Error. Expected %s but got %s\n", sexpr, sact);
    cr_assert_str_eq(sact, sexpr, "");
    if (strcmp(sact, "{}") != 0) {
        free(sact); sact = NULL;
    }
}

Test(removNb, ShouldPassAllTheTestsProvided) {
    dotest(26, "{{15, 21}{21, 15}}");
    dotest(100 , "{}");
    dotest(37 , "{{21, 31}{31, 21}}");
    dotest(101 , "{{55, 91}{91, 55}}");
}
```

This task confused me a little just by the fact that the function is expected to return a pointer to a pointer to an array of structs... To me it seems like one too much excess pointer.
So, is there a problem in the testing code? I kind of struggle to fully understand it yet...
Or is my solution actually improperly implemented? If so, what could I change to not cause memory errors?

Comment: I have only skimmed your question, but generally when something weird like this happens, it is because you're doing something wrong which allows the compiler to do whatever it wants - which might often be what you wanted, but not always

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: `return &pairs;` returns the address of a local variable which leads to undefined behaviour. There may be more errors elsewhere. You probably want `Pair* removNb(long long n, int* length)` and `return pair;`.

Comment: There is a very important warning provided by the compiler. (If you had shown that text as text instead of graphics, I would have copied it here.) Putting that message into Google should provide lots of useful links. Understanding all warnings should be your first step while solving strange problems.

Comment: "_even tho I get some warnings about memory reallocation, but I'm new to C and am trying to just get things to work for now._" Being new is not an excuse to ignore warnings... quite the opposite! If you have warnings about memory allocation, your code does not "work". If it _seems_ to, you're relying on undefined behaviour, and your code is a bomb waiting to explode. You need to fix the warnings. Don't ignore them.

Comment: regarding: `Pair* pairs = malloc(0);`  this is not a valid statement.  Suggest: `Pair* pairs = NULL;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh damn, found the solution. That problem was caused because I was trying to allocate memory for the array of structs as a whole. But in the task description it is stated in the end:

> in C:
> removNb(26) should return  {{15, 21}{21, 15}} tested by way of strings.
> Function removNb should return a pointer to an allocated array of Pair pointers, each one also allocated.

So all was needed done is allocating memory for a struct every time it is going to be created and push a pointer to that struct to the array of pointers to structs... Uhhh O_o

The solution so far:

```
typedef struct {
    long long first;
    long long snd;
} Pair;
// fill length with the number of pairs in your array of pairs
Pair** removNb(long long n, int* length) 
{
    int idx = 0;
    Pair** res = NULL;

    for (long long i = 1; i <= n; i += 1)
    {
        for (long long j = 1; j <= n; j += 1)
        {
            long long product = i * j;
            long long sum = 0;
            for (long long g = 1; g <= n; g += 1)
            {
                if (g != i && g != j)
                {
                    sum += g;
                }    
            }

            if (product == sum)
            {
                Pair *pair = malloc(sizeof(Pair));
                pair->first = i;
                pair->snd = j;
                res = realloc(res, sizeof(Pair*) * (idx + 1));
                res[idx] = pair;
                idx += 1;
            }
        }
    }

    *length = idx;
    return res;
}
```

It still doesn't pass all the tests due to being unoptimized and causing a timeout, but that's a different problem. On my way to solving it right now :)

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a pointer to pointer here. You are returning the address of a local variable instead of the allocated pointer.

```
Pair* removNb(long long n, int* length)
{
    Pair* pairs = malloc(0);
    ....
    return pairs;
}
```

If you need to pointer to pointer, then you have to provide some memory to it as well.

```
Pair** removNb(long long n, int* length)
{
    Pair** rc = malloc(sizeof(Pair**));
    Pair* pairs = malloc(0);
    ....

    *rc = pairs;
    return rc;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I also thought it isn't needed, but the provided testing code expects the return value to be Pair**

Comment: You still have to provide memory for that as well then. See my update.